# Error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, estructuras

tengo que hacer una cola circular que admita strings pero tengo un error al pasar el elemento leido en push, ya estuve revisando como se podia guardar el elemente que lei a el tipo que cree llamado "a" en la estructura, al principio lo hice con solo numero y no tuve mayor problema pero ahora al pasarlo a char fue mi problema, se agradece bastante la ayuda

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>

#define max 100

int elem=0,belem=-1,c=0; 

struct ccircular{
  char a;
};

void push(struct ccircular *aux,char x[],int num)
{
  int i;
  if(c==num)
  {
    printf("COLA LLENA jajaja XD\n"); return;
  }
  belem++; 
  belem=belem%num;
  if(c!=num)
    c++;
  i++;
  (aux+belem)->a=x; //error here
}

int main()
{
  struct ccircular *aux;
  char x[20];
  int num,p,ch;

  printf("De que tamaño quiere la cola\n");
  scanf("%d",&num);system("cls");
  aux=(struct ccircular *)malloc(num*(sizeof(struct ccircular)));
  while (1)
  {
    printf("MENU\n 1.-Insertar \n 2.-Eliminar \n 3.-Mostrar \n 4.-Eliminar toda la cola \n 5.-Salir \n");
    scanf("%d",&ch);system("cls");

    switch(ch)
    {
    case 1:
      printf("Ingrese elemento\n");
      scanf("%d",&x);
      push(aux,x,num);
      printf("Regresando en un segundo\n");Sleep(1000);
      break;
    }

    printf("\n Desea Continuar \n [1] SI [0] NO \n");
    scanf("%d",&x);system("cls");
    if(x==0)
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: En el `case 1:` le has agregado en el primer parámetro un `%d`, cuando debería ser `%s`, debido a que, la variable `x` es de tipo `char*`, por ende, lo que se debería pedir al usuario es una cadena.

Answer (score 0):

C **no tiene** el concepto de *buffer*, *array*, *formación*, *arreglo*, o como queramos llamarlo.

Esto

```
char x[]
```

Es una *perla sintáctica* que el compilador interpreta, literalmente, como

```
char *x
```

Y eso es el error:

```
(aux+belem)->a=x;
```

Puesto que `x` es, literalmente, **un puntero**, esa instrucción está intentado asignar **un puntero a un entero** (de tipo `char`, tal y como se definió en tu `struct ccircular`)..

La solución es muy simple. Puesto que `x` es un puntero, basta con *indireccionarlo*:

```
(aux+belem)->a=*x;
```

Comment: *C no tiene el concepto de buffer, array, formación, arreglo..* ¿Por qué no tiene el concepto de array?

Comment: ¿ Algunas vez has podido asignar un *array* a otro ? `char x[5]; char y[5]; y = x;`

Comment: Eso no explica porque en C no existe el concepto de array. Hasta el [libro oficial](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~hilder/cs833/Other%20Reference%20Materials/The%20C%20Programming%20Language.pdf) de C menciona el concepto de `array`. Si en C no existiera los arrays, no se pudiera hacer esto: `char x[] = {'T', 'R', 'A', 'U', 'M', 'A'};`. Por ejemplo, el concepto de "pase por referencia" en C no existe, porque el mismo Dennis Ritchie lo menciona en su libro.

Comment: Puntualizo: No existen en el estilo de otros lenguajes, como elementos autónomos y con sentido propio. Un *array* no es mas que un *favor* que nos hace el compilador de reservar un cierto bloque de memoria y devolvernos un puntero al mismo.